# I want to execute a piece of code when the window is closed in vsts?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

I want to delete a query when the user closes the query tab in TFS server which is open .

I am using typescript to develop vsts extensions . here i want to delete one query when user closes a window

Answer (score 0):

No such event that can capture the query tab/query result close action in VSTS.